# If pop's have the same distribution but different parameters, can the merged population also have that distrib?

Tags: distributions, mixture-distribution, aggregation, pooling

There is a substantial literature on identifying the best-fitting distribution for income and wealth data. Candidates have included the log-normal, Gamma, Singh-Maddala, Dagum type I and generalized Beta of second kind.  Usually the assumption is that there is likely to be one such distribution applying to all countries, or at least all capitalist nations, and to sub-national as well as national data.

My question is this: can it be true that the states in a nation have the same distribution as the nation, but with different parameters? Are there any continuous distributions that have a closed-form expression and a finite mean and variance with the property that, when you merge two or more populations with the same distribution type but different parameters, the merged population will have a distribution of the same type (perhaps subject to restrictions on the distribution of the parameters)?

If so, is there a list of such distributions, or some way of finding or characterizing them, or of understanding what restrictions this property implies?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were any; for instance, adding 50 unimodal distributions *could* lead to a distribution with 50 modes!

Comment: Sketch of proof of @Peter Flom's claim: any such family would be closed under arbitrary finite mixtures, whence so would their CFs, implying the moments would be linear functions of the parameters, leading to the conclusion that all CFs must be in the form $\exp(-ikt)$, whence the *only* such family is generated by the improper uniform "distribution" on the real line.

Comment: @whuber: Let me restate your conclusion as it applies to my example, and see if you still approve it, for it seems very strong: If a distribution family, say the generalized beta of the 2nd kind, is the best fit for the income distribution of a nation, it _cannot_ also be best fit for the income distribution within states, if the parameters for the states vary. I think you are not allowing for restricted parameter distribution, e.g. if height is normal in states, with equal variance for all states, and the state means are normally distributed, the national distribution will be approx. normal.